# PHP Twitter Style Date

Tags: php

I am wanting to format my date with a Twitter style format however all the examples only have the x hours ago. What I would like...if possible, is:

```
- X min ago
- X hours ago
- Yesterday
- Thursday (or other days)
- 17 December
```

X min/hour ago and yesterday are pretty self explanatory but the day should be used if the date is greater than today and yesterday and the day falls within the current week (week starting Sunday).

The 17 December is if the date is greater than any day in the current week.

I am hoping this can be done. Cheers

Comment: Sure, it can be done. Have you tried anything already? Where are you stuck? Did you have a look through [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+time+ago)?

Comment: Yeah I tried an example here http://www.skidoosh.co.uk/php/create-twitter-like-date-formatted-strings-with-php/ but I am not sure how I would pass in the date.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled "php twitter date" and found the second result gave this script that does exactly what you want:

http://www.skidoosh.co.uk/php/create-twitter-like-date-formatted-strings-with-php/

You could then edit the output formatting to display the types of information your wish.